# Fragment view is not visible although onCreateView is called

Tags: android, fragment

I am using multiple fragments and also viewpagers. Depending on the state of the app, i display a particular fragment. However, i have some trouble with it. When i call show,attach or replace fragment, the fragment view is not displayed although onCreateView is called.If i change the orientation, the view become visible. I am doing everything on UI thread. A sample code is below:

```
 private void replaceFragment(Fragment newFragment1, String tag1, boolean hide) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(APPLIANCE_ID, appId);
    args.putString(APPLIANCE_TYPE, appType);
    args.putString(APPLIANCE_NAME, appName);

    newFragment1.setArguments(args);
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.detail_fragment_container, newFragment1, tag1);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    ft.commit();
    getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
}
```

I am using FrameLayout as container layout. I looked nearly all questions at stackoverflow.

Comment: who call replaceFragment?

Comment: Activity containing fragments.